How can I access part of the data related to CATS regression analysis – a model-based approach to studying trait-based community assembly?
I am looking for some data related to CATS regression analysis so that I can prepare my data based on it. If possible, in an Excel with abundance data and plant traits. Is there anyone who has worked in this field? To be able to help and guide in data preparation.
